# Python Graphs / Page that I can upload/send to colleagues

Tags: python, graph, charts, data-visualization

Im looking to make graphs or charts in Python that I would like to send or upload to colleagues, where they have access to the interactive charts, and the charts would update as I change the data on my PC.
Or maybe colleagues can update the file, and it will reflect the new data automatically.

Is that doable in Python ?
Do I have to upload into a cloud location ? or can it be done through an executable file ?

thx

Answer (score 1):

You could create a client program which retrieves new/updated files from a remote ftp server.

For the server you could just have an ftp server which a python program connects to and lists all available charts which it will give them the option to view and download the images (UI).

As for updating the graphs you could just have a folder with a python script which automatically adds new files/changes to the ftp server which will be available to your colleges via the script.